# Placing point symbol on center of polygon in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, symbology

I'd like to symbolize polygons with a point at the centroid. Does anyone have suggestions how to accomplish this without creating a new shapefile?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the symbology option 'multiple attributes' and set the size min/max for the symbol to the same, and it will create a dot in the middle of each polygon. also, you could probably do the same with maplex labeling to place a '.' label at the centroid of each shape

Answer (score 1):

I would use the "centroid" tool and symbolize the attributes created from the polygon layer used as an input.

Comment: I'm not sue what you mean by "symbolize the attribute". Could you elaborate?

Comment: the field you use to symbolize...that's the attribute. doubleclick on the layer created from the centroid tool and select "symbology". From the Fields "Value" pull down menu, select the field (the attribute) you want the centroid points to be symbolized by.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by adding a point symbol as a backgound to a label on the polygon layer and then making the label text invisible.

Comment: This totally worked for me as a quick fix. You do have to add some label text (just the fixed string "." will work), and then set the text color to "No color".